# How to allow blank user inputs to pass through Eloquent pluck()?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a user input text box where users can specify a specific allergen to avoid when pulling a recipe (plucked by it's id). For example, if users input 'pineapple' it will search the ingredients table for a match with 'pineapple' and avoid pulling the recipe_id assosciated with that ingredient.

**The code in Controller:**

```
$suited = $request->suitable_for;
$specificallerg = $request->specific_allergen;

$recipenew = Recipe::where('recipe.suitable_for', $suited)
    ->whereDoesntHave('ingredients', function($QBspecificallergens) use($specificallerg) {
        $QBspecificallergens->where('recipeingredientsmain.ingredientname', 'like', '%specificallerg%');
      })->pluck('id');
```

However, the issue is that users should be able to leave the user text blank and the search will continue for other aspects. The current issue is that if the users leave the text input blank, nothing is plucked (array is empty). Is there any way to allow a blank field to pass? I could have an if statement checking if the user input is empty, and if it is empty then simply remove that ->whereDoesntHave of the code. But is there any other way  to solve this?

Comment: I think completely omitting the `whereDoesntHave()` block if nothing is entered (as you suggested) is perfectly fine. Something like `$query = Recipe::where('recipe.suitable_for', $suited);`, then `if($specificallerg) { $query = $query->whereDoesntHave(...); }`, then `$recipenew = $query->pluck('id');` (or via `when()` as illustrated below; same logic, different approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$recipenew = Recipe::where('recipe.suitable_for', $suited);

if ($request->specific_allergen) {
   $recipenew = $recipenew->whereDoesntHave('ingredients', function($QBspecificallergens) use($specificallerg) {
        $QBspecificallergens->where('recipeingredientsmain.ingredientname', 'like', '%specificallerg%');
      });
}

$recipenew = $recipenew->pluck('id);
```

Answer (score 4):

use `when`

```
$recipenew = Recipe::where('recipe.suitable_for', $suited)
            ->when(!empty($specificallerg),function ($QBspecificallergens)use($specificallerg){
                $QBspecificallergens->whereDoesntHave('ingredients', function($QBspecificallergens) use($specificallerg) {

                    $QBspecificallergens->where('recipeingredientsmain.ingredientname', 'like', '%specificallerg%');
                });
            })
            ->pluck('id');
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses
Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-when